# Retain the latest record in hive table

Tags: sql, performance, hive, bigdata, domain-data-modelling

I have a table with around 100 million records, on a daily basis we get around 100K records with updates.
Currently we are applying a `ROW_NUMBER` on the timestamp and picking up the latest record by doing `UNION ALL`.

With this approach we are facing serious performance issues.

Can you suggest any better approach from performance perspective?

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tgt_tbl
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT row_number() over (partition by acct_num order by time_stamp)
FROM 
     (SELECT acct_num , time_stamp FROM tgt_tbl
       UNION ALL 
      SELECT acct_num , time_stamp FROM Incremental table
     )t1
 ) t2
WHERE rnum = 1
```

Comment: Do you have the account number column for this table getting incremented in Ascending order with new data on daily basis ?

Comment: account number doest follow any order, but the time stamp is incremental.account_number has other attributes that are updated

Comment: Yes, This approach will be depreciated. you can restrict updates limited to the partitions which you are trying to update and use full outer join instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939313/optimize-the-join-performance-with-hive-partition-table