# Hive how to merge tmp table into history table based on some cols. if Exist then ignore, if not then insert

Tags: hive, hql, data-warehouse

I have a table called `zhihu_answer`. I take it as the warehouse to store data scraped day by day. Every day there will create a `zhihu_answer_tmp` table storing the newly scraped data, which shared the same data stucture as `zhihu_answer`.

The DDL is:

```
createtab_stmt  
CREATE TABLE `zhihu_answer`(    
  `admin_closed_comment` boolean,   
  `answer_content` string,  
  `answer_created` string,  
  `answer_id` string,   
  `insert_time` string,         
  `voteup_count` int)   
PARTITIONED BY (`year_month` string)
```

I took `answer_id` and `insert_time` as the unique key, my question is how to merge the new data in `zhihu_answer_tmp` into the history data table `zhihu_answer` based on `answer_id` and `insert_time`?

In specific, if there is a row with the same `answer_id and insert_time` existed in `zhihu_answer`, then do nothing, simply ignore(for Idempotency, prevent side-effect from inserting data more than twice).

On the other hand, if there is not any rows with the same `answer_id and insert_time` as `zhihu_answer_tmp` in `zhihu_answer`, then insert the rows(newly scraped data).

Thanks for any advice or any solution the question.

Comment: you can use full outer join with case statements to complete the task.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939313/optimize-the-join-performance-with-hive-partition-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive: Best way to do incremetal updates on a main table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709411/hive-best-way-to-do-incremetal-updates-on-a-main-table)

Comment: thanks for your advice, I take it for reference.